# Using AWS API Gateway generated SDK for both authenticated and anonymous access

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was playing around with API gateway for a couple hours and I got stuck when dealing with different resources authentication requirements. It seems like there isn't a way to access public api endpoints through AWSAPIGatewayClient generated classes.

Here is the scenario:

```
/moments
GET - Auth: None
POST - Auth: AWS_IAM.
```

API Gateway generates the following:

```
@interface CLIFamilyMomentsClient: AWSAPIGatewayClient

+ (instancetype)defaultClient;
+ (void)registerClientWithConfiguration:(AWSServiceConfiguration *)configuration forKey:(NSString *)key;
+ (instancetype)clientForKey:(NSString *)key;
+ (void)removeClientForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (AWSTask *)momentsGet;
- (AWSTask *)momentsPost:(CLICreateMomentRequest *)body;

@end
```

It turns out that momentsGet is looking for some sort of an AWS Cognito credential even though this is a public accessible endpoint.

Code I'm executing:

```
let serviceClient = CLIFamilyMomentsClient.defaultClient()
let awsTask = serviceClient.momentsGet()
awsTask.continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if task.error != nil {
        print(task.error)
    } else {                
        if let response = task.result as! CLIListMomentsResponse?{
            print(response.items.count)
        }
    }            
    return nil
}
```

Output

```
2015-11-22 19:40:17.603 FamilyMoments[610:169366] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:428 | __73-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider getCredentialsWithCognito:authenticated:]_block_invoke | GetCredentialsForIdentity failed. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to Identity 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX' is forbidden.}]
2015-11-22 19:40:17.605 FamilyMoments[610:169366] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:527 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke352 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to Identity 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX' is forbidden.}]
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to Identity 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX' is forbidden.}
```

Is there something I'm missing or API gateway generated SDK isn't intended to work with both authenticated and anonymous access together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got that working. It turns out that you can register different `AWSServiceConfiguration` configurations and use them separately.

On AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // AWS Cognito Access for authenticated requests
    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    let configurationAuth = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configurationAuth

    // Anonymous Access
    let configurationAnonymous = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: AWSAnonymousCredentialsProvider())
    CLIFamilyMomentsClient.registerClientWithConfiguration(configurationAnonymous, forKey: "anonymousAccess")

    return true
}
```

for public accessible endpoints

```
let serviceClient = CLIFamilyMomentsClient(forKey: "anonymousAccess")
let awsTask = serviceClient.momentsGet()
awsTask.continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if task.error != nil {
        print(task.error)
    } else {
        print(task.result)
    }
    return nil
}
```

for authenticated endpoints

```
let serviceClient = CLIFamilyMomentsClient.defaultClient()
let awsTask = service.momentsPost(createMoment)
awsTask.continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if task.error != nil {
        print(task.error)
    } else {
        print(task.result)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope this helps future developers struggling with it.

Comment: I would clasify this as a "work around", but should definitely unblock you until the generated SDK handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the [API Gateway forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220434&tstart=0) this is currently a limitation of the generated SDKs. We have a backlog item to address this in the future.

Comment: It seems like I could figure out a way to solve it. Please see my answer. Thanks mate